# React.js basic set up

Tags: reactjs

Please help. I am brand new so I know this is very basic but I can't figure out what is wrong with my set up. No matter what I do I keep getting syntax errors. I place the code in codepen and it worked. I need to get my local working though.

I have a dist folder with a index.html and a index.js

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>React</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
  <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
</div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

error

unexpected token<

I also tried this code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>React</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react-container"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const { createElement } = React
const{ render } = ReactDom

const title = createElement(
'h1',
{id: 'title', className: 'header'},
 'Hello World'
)

render(
title,
document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

error ReactDom is not defined

or

```
const title = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  {id: 'title', className: 'header'},
  'Hello World'
)

ReactDOM.render(
  tile,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

with a error title is not defined

Comment: well, in your last example, at the very least, you have `ReactDOM.render(tile ...)` - note `tile` instead of `title`. For "ReactDom" is not defined, it's probably `ReactDOM` - note the capitalized `DOM`

Comment: Have you considered using Create React App? It's a really awesome way to get started easily: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Three different errors.

First, `JSX` is not (technically) JavaScript - you need a transpiler like Babel. `<h1>...</h1>` is JSX.

Second, it's probably `ReactDOM`, not `ReactDom` - capitalization matters. How did you import `ReactDOM`? `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`? if so, capitalize.

Third, and finally, `tile` in your `render` call needs to be `title`.

Take your time, check your code, and breathe.